# ios - NSLog showing that detailedView is not displayed in the right order

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, string, storyboard

I am trying to pass data from one ViewController to another using storyboard.

Please note this log message:

```
2012-11-13 22:25:41.711 Modern Notes[8991:15d03] DetailView - (null) 
2012-11-13 22:25:41.714 Modern Notes[8991:15d03] MainView - {
CurrentDate = "2012-11-13 05:12:46 +0000";
NoteInString = "This is the first note. It will appear here while testing the app.";
}
```

You will see that DetailView - has nothing and that MainView show the contents off an array.
The Array is passed on from the MainView. Now both log Messages are generated by this line:

```
NSLog(@"DetailView - %@", _notedict);
```

and

```
NSLog(@"MainView - %@", noteDetailViewControler.notedict);
```

Where notedict is the Dictionary that holds the information. As you can see (i think) in theory both Log messages should display this array right??

**Now it seems strange to me that DetailView is being shown in the Log before MainView where I think it should be the other way around??**

Cheers for any tips and happy to provide any details if needed.

**EDIT:**

ok, so this is where I am sorting my details out:

in the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I have a line

```
noteDetailViewControler.notedict = [_listNotes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now I think my problem is that this line is only set locally and is not carried over to another viewcontroller - am I right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `_notedict` is not yet set, or already removed again, when you log it in the DetailView. You need to show us, **when (in which method) you initalize** the data, **when you log** it and **when you show** the mainView / detailView. We can not not help anymore with the information given right now.

Comment: Ok, but if I still need to initialize it which I agree is the problem, how come MainView can call it from the same file??

Comment: I have added the method above - hope it is what you need??

Comment: It is not working yet, but you got me on the right track - hence the accepted answer:-)